# проверить mime type

Tags: php

[image: code]

Здравствуйте, есть код который принимает картинку из инпута, обрезает лишнее, снимает кодировку и сохраняет картинку в нужную папку с расширением jpg. У меня вопрос, как можно проверить является ли картинка изображением? тоесть только .png .jpeg .jpg .bmp

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно:

```
$info = getimagesize($this->file['tmp_name']);
$info['mime'];
```

Привожу пример класса валидации изображения. Думаю, что тут всё понятно.

```
/**
 * Класс для работы с изрображениями
 */
class Image
{
private $file;
private $error;
private $allow = array('png' => 'image/png', 'gif' => 'image/gif',
    'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg', 'jpg' => 'image/jpeg');

public function __construct($file) {
    $this->file = $file;
    $this->error = NULL;
}

public function __destruct() {
    if ($this->file && $this->file['tmp_name']) {
        unlink($this->file['tmp_name']);
    }
}

public function validate() {
    $this->error = NULL;

    if (!$this->file['tmp_name']) {
        $this->error = 'Файл не загружен (слишком большой)';
        return FALSE;
    }
    // проверка непосредственно расширения файла
    $file_info = pathinfo($this->file['name']);
    if (!isset($file_info['extension'])
            || !in_array(mb_strtolower($file_info['extension'], 'UTF-8'), array_keys($this->allow))) {
        $this->error = 'Разрешено загружать только '.implode(', ', array_keys($this->allow));
        return FALSE;
    }
    // проверка типа файла и mime информации об изображении
    $info = getimagesize($this->file['tmp_name']);
    if (!in_array($this->file['type'], $this->allow) || !in_array($info['mime'], $this->allow)) {
        $this->error = 'Разрешено загружать только '.implode(', ', array_keys($this->allow));
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
}
```